# Inverse of matrix*1/2 will be double of original matrix inverse

Tags: matrices

Lets say matrix$ A = \begin{bmatrix}2& 4& 6\\8& 10& 12\\14& 16& 18 \end{bmatrix}$

and $$B=A/2=\begin{bmatrix} 1&2&3\\4&5&6\\7&8&9\end{bmatrix}$$

then inverse of B= 2 times (inverse of A), i.e. $B^{-1}= 2 A^{-1}$

I request your expert advice to understand its meaning. Thank you in advance.

Comment: if $bB=I$ then $2b(\frac12B)=I$ (here $b=B^{-1}$)

Comment: If $B = AC$ and both $A$ and $C$ are invertible matrices, then $B^{-1} = (AC)^{-1} = C^{-1}A^{-1}$.  Now... note that $A\cdot \frac{1}{2} = A\cdot (\frac{1}{2}I)$ and so $B^{-1} = (A\cdot \frac{1}{2}I)^{-1} = (\frac{1}{2}I)^{-1}A^{-1} = (2I)A^{-1} = 2\cdot A^{-1}$.  It should be pretty obvious why $(\frac{1}{2}I)^{-1} = 2I$

Comment: It means the same thing that it does for real numbers: the multiplicative inverse of $x/2$ is $2/x$.

Answer (score 3):

If $A^{-1}$ exists and $\lambda\ne0$, then $(\lambda\cdot A)^{-1}=\frac{1}{\lambda}A^{-1}$.

But actually, the example you mentioned doesn't work since

$$
\det\begin{bmatrix}2&4&6\\8&10&12\\14&16&18\\\end{bmatrix}
=0.
$$

Hence $A$ is not invertible.